# Is it OK to wait on a child process from a thread different to the one creating the process?

Tags: python, multithreading, unix

I was bit recently by a quirk when handling SIGTERM in Python multi-threaded programs. Does something similar applies to other functions in the os module? More particularly, do I need to always wait (e.g. os.wait) on a process from the main thread?

Some code to illustrate my point:

```
class MyService:
    def stop_child_process(self, p):
         assert is instance(p, subprocess.Popen)
         stopper = threading.Thread( partial(self._wait_for_child, p) )
         stopper.start()

    def _wait_for_child(self, p):
         ...
         p.wait()
         ...
```

Will this work, or will it somehow manage to blow-up in production?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do here. Why do you need to wait on the subprocess? What do you hope to accomplish by waiting on it in another thread? The other thread should be able to wait for the process to finish, but that won't prevent program from closing with the child process and thread still active unless you set daemon=False on the thread.

Comment: Thanks @zstewart . Yes, I understand what you say about the process exiting. My question is simply if this is not one of those cases where the main thread has special privileges regarding OS services that other threads don't have.

Comment: @zstewart The `wait()` is necessary to prevent zombie processes and waiting in another thread allows the waiting program to go on with its business while waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter from which thread you are calling `Popen.wait()` or `os.wait()`.  It doesn't have to be the same thread the process was started from.